# Fastest way to detect duplicate numbers on array vb.net 2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have this project that let user inputs 5 different numbers from 1 to 50. But I want to validate it before saving to DB that i will be 5 unique numbers. What's the best and fastest way to do this?

Comment: You only want to check duplication of numbers or any other processing you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this code

```
Private Function HasDuplicates(ByVal arr As Array) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
        If Not arr(i) Is Nothing Then
            Dim l As Integer = Array.LastIndexOf(arr, arr(i))
            If l <> i Then Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Realize that this will not scale well if you ever need to use it on many elements, as its quadratic in nature.  For 5 items, it's fine, though.

Comment: I think array used for limited number of items and its work faster then any solution i have three programs in which i am using this function after studying alot about duplicates.

Comment: Yes - for less than about 25 items, on my system, this is faster than my approach.  At about 25 it switches, and by 50, this is about 2x slower, and then gets exponentially worse past there...

Comment: If you want to prove that your code work fast then ask this man who questioned. He know better which code run fast.

Comment: Not trying to prove anything (I actually ran a full test, since I was curious) - as I said, for 5 items, this is faster than my code ;)  It just wont scale well to many items...

Answer (score 10):

You can use [HashSet(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) to check this:

```
Dim numbers As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = GetInputFromUser()
Dim hash As HashSet(Of Integer) = new HashSet(Of Integer)(numbers)

Dim unique As Boolean = hash.Count = numbers.Count()
```

This will be much more efficient than options requiring a sort + iteration.

Comment: Are you sure that creating a HashSet copy of your data will be more efficient than sorting and enumerating over 5 numbers?

Comment: @Michael: With 5, probably doesn't matter either way... With more, yes.

Comment: +1: I like this solution because of scalability ...the input may only be 5 integers today, but in 6 months it could be a couple of hundred.

Comment: @IAbstract: Yes, that's always my thinking.  I'd rather use a technique that will handle anything you throw at it, since code or tecniques like this end up getting used elsewhere, or requirements change, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Reed Copsey's suggestion to use hash sets was a good one (I hadn't worked with the HashSet class before).

But I then discovered that the IEnumerable class offers an extension method called Distinct that copies the unique values from a source IEnumerable to a target IEnumerable.

Borrowing the first line of Reed's sample code, here's the new sample VB.NET code:

```
    Dim numbers As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = GetInputFromUser()
    Dim isUnique As Boolean = (numbers.Distinct.Count = numbers.Count)
```

The variable isUnique is True if the numbers IEnumerable contains no duplicate values, or False if it contains one or more duplicate values.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I wanted, works on my integer array so I only needed the second line. And learned something too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put in an array, sort it and check if elements 1,2 2,3 3,4 and 4,5 are different (in a loop).

Comment: @Reed both my sort-compare and your hashset based solution focus more on programmer-time efficiency than on runtime efficiency, as they probably should in the given use case with 5 input values.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pseudocode:

integer numbers[50]
zeroarray(numbers, 50)

integer count = 0;
while (count < 5)
{
   integer value = getinput()

   if (value >= 1 and value <= 50)
     if (numbers[value] = 0)
     {
        count = count + 1
        numbers[value] = 1
     }
     else
        reject duplicate
   else
     reject invalid
}
```

Comment: The value is an index into the array and therefore indicates its value.  No need to store the value itself.  The array could as easily be boolean.

Comment: Ahh, okay - so then, afterwards, you'd do a pass through your entire list to get the selected bits out?

Comment: Another simple optimization you could make to avoid having to scan the entire array when it's time to output to the DB is to have another array of 5 elements and store the values there, using count as an index.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this very simple method:
[Filtering Arrays using LINQ](http://simplyvisualbasic.blogspot.com/2011/09/filtering-arrays-using-linq.html)

Comment: Its an instance of dArray you are filtering. You can check the syntax of LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

To simplifiy lets say the user inputs 5 different numbers from 0 to 49.

You can create a Boolean Array *IsUsed(49)* with 50 elements.

Then when the user input the value iInputNum=30 you can set IsUsed(30)=TRUE.
Next time, when the user input the second value iInputNum=7, you can set IsUsed(7)=TRUE
In this way you can check in a very fast way if the number was already inserted.

```
if IsUsed(iInputNum) then
   'Skip the Input (put the right code here)
else
   'Accept the number
   IsUsed(iInputNum)=TRUE
   'save iInputNum in the database
end if
```

Do not forget to clear the array after inserting all 5 numbers.
Remenber to put the right index in order to handle the number 1-50 (e not 0-49)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate solution, not sure how it compares, efficiency wise, to the other solutions, but it seems to work (uses LINQ).

```
Dim numbers As List<int> = getListOfNumbers()
Dim allUnique As Boolean = numbers.Distinct().Count() = numbers.Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but what about something like this (C#, sorry)?

```
byte[] hits = new byte[51];
byte[] entries = new byte[] { 1, 12, 12, 32, 26, 49 };

foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    hits[entry]++;
}
```

The elements in the `hits` array are automatically initialized to 0. When the `foreach` loop is complete, `hits` will contain the occurrence count for every number in `entries`. If any is greater than 1, you have dupes.