# How to determine if there are repeat values in an array

Tags: vb.net

What I'm trying to do is use 5 textboxes to get a number input from the user and then put those numbers in an array.

How would I go about determining if values repeat in an array? Like if the array ends up being:
{2,3,2,8,4}
I'm not sure how to have the program essentially say "There are 2 textboxes with the value 2."

Thanks.

Comment: You could check each of the five textbox values against the values in the other 4 text boxes to see if they have the same value.

Comment: For each distinct element in the collection, count how many occurrences are in the collection.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365211/fastest-way-to-detect-duplicate-numbers-on-array-vb-net-2005 And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547427/how-to-find-and-count-duplicate-numbers-in-a-string-array-in-vb-net

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example you can use that uses LINQ:

```
Sub Main()
   Dim myArray As Integer() = {2, 3, 2, 8, 4}

   For Each group In myArray _
      .GroupBy(Function(i) i) _
      .Where(Function(grp) grp.Count > 1)

      Console.WriteLine($"There are {group.Count} textboxes with the value {group.Key}.")
   Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick, assuming both arrays are of the same type:

```
Dim hasDupes As Boolean
Dim array1 As Integer() = {3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
Dim array2 As Integer() = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13}

hasDupes = array1.Intersect(array2).Any()
```

If there are any duplicate items, hasDupes will evaluate to true.

Comment: OP is talking about 1 array, not two.